# After prior illegal sex, should he marry someone else, or should he incur the death penalty?

Tags: nikah, fiqh, punishment, zina

My friend faced a problem that is in his career. he had two girlfriends and he  was having sex with both girls. At that time he was not following the rules of Islam properly. Now he  came back to Islam and he want to get married. Should he marry a new girl, or pick any girl that was his relationship?

On the other hand, illegal sex is not supported in Islam; should incur the death penalty?

Comment: Death penalty for *Zina* is for a *Muhsan* (already married) offender.

Answer (score 2):

The had for illegal premarital sex for non married people is covered in the Qur'an:

> The [unmarried] woman or [unmarried] man found guilty of sexual intercourse - lash each one of them with a hundred lashes, and do not be taken by pity for them in the religion of Allah , if you should believe in Allah and the Last Day. And let a group of the believers witness their punishment. ([24:2](http://legacy.quran.com/24/2))

This ruling applies on you if either you have been caught in the act, 4 witnesses can seen you do this, or you have confessed it to a person of authority (a Judge for example). If not you can still repent from it a sincere repentance and lead a good Muslim's live (marrying a chaste girl etc.). This is the best work around you have. And you can stay in fear of a punishment in the hereafter and hope that Allah may forgive you. This certainly depends on how you lead your further life.

For a death penalty you also need a court, witnesses, confession etc. but as said above it doesn't apply for you.

Some evidences:

> Ma'iz ibn Malik came to the Prophet (ﷺ) and admitted fornication twice. But he drove him away. He then came and admitted fornication twice. But he drove him away. He then came and admitted fornication twice. He (the Prophet) said: You have testified to yourself four times. Take him away and stone him to death.  ([Sunan abu Dawod](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/40/76))
>
> Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) as saying: Receive (teaching) from me, receive (teaching) from me. Allah has ordained a way for those (women). When an unmarried male commits adultery with an unmarried female (they should receive) one hundred lashes and banishment for one year. And in case of married male committing adultery with a married female, they shall receive one hundred lashes and be stoned to death.
>   ([Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/29/17))

Comment: In order to carry out all the capital punishments of Islam, an Islamic State with a legitimate caliph as its head needs to exist. One cannot incur or even think of carrying out these punishments of Islam in today's systems of governments.. therefore, all the courts and judges are illegitimate, even if the litigant confesses to them.

Comment: @QaisarKhan that might be right to some extent, but it is primarily your opinion or pretext to call many judgements illegitimate. I in best case only half agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

Hadd punishments can be implemented only under a proper muslim leader and punishments are awarded by a qualified judge.

***Sex before marriage is not punishable by death in Islam***.

To best of my knowledge if you are resident of country like Saudi arab, if it comes to light that you have involved yourself in 2 fornications(sex before marriage), you will be given lashings with a whip.

Repent to Allah and never repeat. You can marry a new partner or same person with whom you were involved, after both have repented sincerely.